# jQuery (intermediate value).imagesLoaded is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-masonry

Need help in debugging a tiny bit of script.

I ma using 'masonry' plugin to arrange numerous divs in a tile manner. The script seems to work fine except I am getting the error `jQuery (intermediate value).imagesLoaded is not a function`

The script in my `.js` file is as follows...

```
var container = document.querySelector('#container2');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  columnWidth: 240,
  itemSelector: '.post',
  isFitWidth: true,
  isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions
  }).imagesLoaded(function() {
     $(this).masonry('reload');
});
```

As I am using Wordpress I am thinking there may be some conflict with another plugin.

Comment: You have to be sure your plugin script imagesLoaded is loaded before using it

Comment: Yes - this is definitely loaded - is it possible that the order in which it loads can make a difference ?

Comment: The order can make a difference, yes. You need to make sure that Masonry loads first. If you use wp_enqueue_script, you can set Masonry as a dependency on your script, and WordPress will load Masonry first.

Answer (score 1):

check your script for **;**

```
$.fn.some = function () {
   return this;
} // without ;
```

will produces an error, also check for return this in jQuery extensions